# Tab bar covering view in iPhone X

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I am testing an app in iPhone X Simulator and I have written code in Objective-c. It has Tab bar view controller and it seems that Tab bar is having more padding than before. I have tested the same app in other simulators and it looks fine. It's throwing this issue in just iPhone X simulator.

This is how the view looks.

[image]

As you can see there's a part of the text that's chipped and the tab bar seems to be covering the white view little bit.

Could anyone please help me with this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

From this [tutorial](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController) and after initialization of tab bar writing this line in appdelegate class

```
(self.tabBarController.tabBar as? ESTabBar)?.itemCustomPositioning = .fillIncludeSeparator
```

Solves my problem of tab bar.